# Presto API to get active workers

Tags: api, rest, presto, trino

I would like to use Presto API to get number of active workers, similar to the info available in PrestoUI.

I want to use the an API similar to (who don't contain this info):

1. https://presto/v1/status
2. https://presto/v1/jmx

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK in latest Trino (formerly Presto SQL) versions the workers cannot be introspected from outside of the cluster, but you can get the listing with SQL:

```
presto> SELECT * FROM system.runtime.nodes;
    node_id    |        http_uri        |   node_version   | coordinator | state
---------------+------------------------+------------------+-------------+--------
 presto-worker | http://172.20.0.3:8081 | 347-137-g4945abe | false       | active
 presto-master | http://172.20.0.4:8080 | 347-137-g4945abe | true        | active
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Is there any way to get uptime of the nodes ?